# JOIN two SELECT statement results

Tags: sql, select, join

Is it possible to join the results of 2 sql SELECT statements as one statement where both are query the same tables, and look for values in the same column?

I want to have the id of a task (which is fine) but then I want to filter out certain values into 2 separate columns.

Currently I get get the data in 2 separately:

```
 SELECT id, string_value as Station FROM table WHERE datatype= 'station'
```

(column datatype doesn't need to be seen)

returns something like:

```
id            Station
task1         station1
task2         station2
```

and then I have

```
SELECT id, string_value as RespondingAction FROM table 
 WHERE datatype='RespondingAction'
```

returning:

```
id             RespondingAction
task1          Approve
task2          Decline
```

I want to basically combine these 2 queries, but I'm not sure how as they both look for the data in the same column. Hopefully the end result would be something like this:

```
id            Station           RespondingAction
task1         station1          Approve
task2         station2          Decline 
task3         station1          Decline
task4         station3          Pending (if null)
```

Sorry if this isn't too clear; I'm new to this and trying my best to work this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, MAX(Station), NVL(Max(RespondingAction), 'Pending')
FROM
  (SELECT id, 
    string_value as Station,
    NULL as RespondingAction
   FROM table
   WHERE dataType = 'station'

   UNION

   SELECT id,
    NULL as Station,
    string_value as RespondingAction
   FROM table
   WHERE dataType = 'RespondingAction')
GROUP By id
```

**EDIT**

you can also try to replace

```
NVL(Max(RespondingAction), 'Pending')
```

by

```
   COALESCE(MAX(RespondingAction), CAST('Pending' AS <the type of column string_value>))
```

Comment: @John misunderstood on first time ;)

Comment: Gave this a bash in TOAD (don't know if I should have mentioned this before, as I said, very new at this).  I'm getting a 'character set mismatch' error on the first line where it hits 'Pending'

Comment: @John you may try to change COALESCE by NVL (you're working with Oracle, right ?)

Comment: @John if it doesn't work, could you give the type of column string_value ?

Comment: THANK YOU! that worked a treat! I've not got much experience with Oracle and this has just kind of been dumped on me! is COALESCE not valid in Oracle?

Comment: @John hmmm, it's not exactly that. It would have also worked with `COALESCE(Max(RepondingAction), CAST('Pending' as <theDataTypeOf string_value>))` Just googled and found that NVL doesn't need that, but I must admit I donnow why.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CASE`

```
SELECT id, 
   case dataType when 'station' 
                 then string_value else 'Pending' end Station,
   case dataType when 'RespondingAction' 
                 then string_value else 'Pending' end RespondingAction
FROM table WHERE datatype IN ('station','RespondingAction')
```